# How to separate a string with a word that looks like Aa*?

Tags: r, regex

I have a df like this:

```
df<-structure(list(col3 = c("Text or A ny V alue", "Text or A ny V alue", 
"Text or A ny V alue", "Categorical select multiple", "Categorical select one (nominal) 3", 
"Categorical select one (nominal) 13", "Categorical select one (nominal) 71", 
"CHMUNIT Text or A ny V alue", "Categorical select one (nominal) 71", 
"Text or A ny V alue", "Categorical select one (nominal) 3", 
"Categorical select one (nominal) 3", "Categorical select one (nominal) 3", 
"Text or A ny V alue", "Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Text or A ny V alue", "Categorical select one (nominal) 3", 
"Categorical select one (nominal) 71", "DSMETA DT Date", "DSMETA ST Text or A ny V alue", 
"Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", "DSPA THDT Date", "Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Text or A ny V alue", "Text or A ny V alue", "Text or A ny V alue", 
"Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", "Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3", 
"Categorical select one (nominal) 71", "V DCO V O S Text or A ny V alue", 
"V DCO V O S Text or A ny V alue", "V DCO V O S Text or A ny V alue", 
"Categorical select multiple 44", "Categorical select one (nominal) 3"
)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to get the parts which are all uppercase from the beginning to a new var. How can I do it?
I ran into the problem that I also get the first letter of word such as "Text". Thinking of gsub the first word that looks Aa* to `?` then use it as separation. But don't know how to achieve it? Any suggestion?

The output should be sth in green. if can remove the spce in new_var at the same step, that would be even better.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` here along with `grepl`:

```r
df$New_Var <- ifelse(grepl("^[A-Z]+\\b(?: [A-Z]+\\b)*", df$col3),
                     sub("^([A-Z]+\\b(?: [A-Z]+\\b)*).*$", "\\1", df$col3),
                     "")
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
^                    from the beginning of col3
    [A-Z]+           match an all-caps word
    \b               word boundary
    (?: [A-Z]+\b)*   followed by space and another all-caps word
                     zero or more times
```

We first use `grepl` to detect if the `col3` value be match.  If so, we then use `sub` to capture the all-caps portion, otherwise we use empty string as a non-matching placeholder.

Comment: Wonderful idea!

Comment: @Stataq `\1` (or sometimes `$1` in other programming languages) refers to the first _capture_ group defined in the regex.  In this case, it is the series of all-caps words beginning each match.

Comment: By the way, the pattern you want for your follow-up question might be this: `^.*?([A-Z]+\\b(?: [A-Z]+\\b)*)$` ... this would capture all all-caps words occurring at the _end_ of one of your columns.

Comment: Many thanks. Isn't `^` means start of string?  Will that require us to get a whole col2 that start from beginning to end are all uppercase?

Comment: If you want to use a capture group, then you need to match the entire column, from the start, even though you really only want to capture the end.

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution is this:

```
library(stringr)
df$NewVar <- str_extract(df$col3, "^[A-Z\\s]{2,}(?![a-z])")
```

You extract the substring with upper-case letters and white spaces `[A-Z\\s]` occurring at string start `^` if there are at least 2 (`{2,}`) such upper-case letters and if the last upper-case letter is not followed by a lower-case one (`(?![a-z])`).

Result:

```
df
                                  col3       NewVar
1                  Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
2                  Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
3                  Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
4          Categorical select multiple         <NA>
5   Categorical select one (nominal) 3         <NA>
6  Categorical select one (nominal) 13         <NA>
7  Categorical select one (nominal) 71         <NA>
8          CHMUNIT Text or A ny V alue     CHMUNIT 
9  Categorical select one (nominal) 71         <NA>
10                 Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
11  Categorical select one (nominal) 3         <NA>
12  Categorical select one (nominal) 3         <NA>
13  Categorical select one (nominal) 3         <NA>
14                 Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
15  Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3         <NA>
16                 Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
17  Categorical select one (nominal) 3         <NA>
18 Categorical select one (nominal) 71         <NA>
19                      DSMETA DT Date   DSMETA DT 
20       DSMETA ST Text or A ny V alue   DSMETA ST 
21  Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3         <NA>
22                      DSPA THDT Date   DSPA THDT 
23  Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3         <NA>
24                 Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
25                 Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
26                 Text or A ny V alue         <NA>
27  Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3         <NA>
28  Categorical yes/no (dichotomous) 3         <NA>
29 Categorical select one (nominal) 71         <NA>
30     V DCO V O S Text or A ny V alue V DCO V O S 
31     V DCO V O S Text or A ny V alue V DCO V O S 
32     V DCO V O S Text or A ny V alue V DCO V O S 
33      Categorical select multiple 44         <NA>
34  Categorical select one (nominal) 3         <NA>
```

Comment: Note that your regex pattern would also match things like `CASH$` ... [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/1otV3e/1)